# How to Join Multiple Queries with Multiple Conditions in Mysql from Single Table in PHP?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have a single table in MySQL

```
------------------------------
| ID | Subject | Marks | Term |
-------------------------------
| 1  | English | 45    | 1    |
| 2  | Hindi   | 34    | 1    |
| 3  | English | 54    | 2    |
| 4  | Hindi   | 33    | 2    |
------------------------------
```

I want the output like:

```
--------------------------------------
| Subject | Marks_Term1 | Marks_Term2 |
--------------------------------------
| English |  45         | 54          |
|  Hindi  |  34         | 33          |
--------------------------------------
```

Please help me with the code, reply will be appreciated.

```
SELECT marks_entry.subject_id, marks_entry.main_exam, marks_entry.main_exam
FROM marks_entry 
WHERE marks_entry.term_id = 1 
 LEFT JOIN SELECT marks_entry.subject_id, marks_entry.main_exam, marks_entry.main_exam FROM marks_entry WHERE marks_entry.term_id = 2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried putting JOIN between the queries, but its not working

Comment: Add the code you have tried

Comment: so you want on each row subject and all the votes related to that subject?

Comment: right @AlbertoSinigaglia

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working: @Jens

SELECT marks_entry.subject_id, marks_entry.main_exam, marks_entry.main_exam FROM marks_entry WHERE marks_entry.term_id = 1 LEFT JOIN SELECT marks_entry.subject_id, marks_entry.main_exam, marks_entry.main_exam FROM marks_entry WHERE marks_entry.term_id = 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT A.Subject, A.Marks AS Marks_Term1, B.Marks AS Marks_Term2
FROM {tableName} A, {tableName} B
WHERE A.Subject = B.Subject
```

Comment: This worked, But There is one problem , if term 2 marks in not entered then i want to show blank in the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation to pivot your dataset:

```
select 
    subject,
    max(case when term = 1 then marks end) marks_term1,
    max(case when term = 2 then marks end) marks_term2
from mytable
group by subject
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, But Can You Please Guide me if I have Multiple Conditions. Actually I have a greater table with multiple Subjects with different classes. If I am trying to run this code its showing all the subjects assigned to different classes also and in marks its showing NULL.